# MonoTouch translation does not work for 'de'

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, xamarin.ios, localizable.strings

I'm having problems with the MonoTouch/iOS translation feature. I have English and German translation files (Localizable.strings) in the `en.lproj` and `de.lproj` folders, both files are set to `Build Action = Content`.

The problem is, only the English translation works on both the simulator and the device. The German translation does not work, neither on the device nor on the simulator.

I tried all of the following:

- Clean and Rebuild
- Deleted the app on the simulator/device, changed the language to German, rebooted the simulator/device, reinstalled the app
- Restarted MonoTouch, restarted my Mac
- Combinations of these

What am I missing? How to "instruct" MonoTouch to switch to the UI language of the device? How to debug errors like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the problem was that the German file contained umlauts and was not encoded in UTF-8. If you have the same problem, just convert the files to UTF-8 and try again.